# Indesign: Keep multiple paragraphs (of different styles) sets together

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, paragraph-styles, grep

Is it possible with a script or GREP styles to keep together multiple sets of paragraphs which can contain 5-6 different paragraph styles though the start and end paragraph styles are always the same – basically those and everything between should kept together, or moved to the top of a new column or text frame.

First number is {LOT Number}, and the end price is {LOT Estimate} paragraph styles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

See example below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Keep Options** to achieve this.

### In the first Paragraph Style's options (LOT Number)

- Under *Keep Options*, check *Keep Lines Together* and choose *All Lines in Paragraph*. (As the name says, this makes sure to keep all lines of the paragraph together and never break across columns/frames. Not strictly needed in this case since it seems like the LOT number is just a short number, but best to add it for a robust solution.)

[image]

### In all other Paragraph Styles' options

- Under *Keep Options*, check *Keep with Previous*. (This makes sure the paragraph will always stick to the previous paragraph. If there isn't room for both paragraphs they will both jump to the next column/frame.)
- Under *Keep Options*, check *Keep Lines Together* and choose *All Lines in Paragraph*.

[image]

See [the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-paragraphs.html) for more information about Keep Options.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much Wolff! That was so easy and rather ashamed I didn't manage to work that out when I'd tried a few similar combinations in the keep options in the past - obviously not quite the right ones. Will save a lot of time on many of my projects so very much appreciated advice. 